# Wishlist without left navigation

Tags: navigation, customer-account, wishlist

somebody know if I can see the wishlist but just the view.phtml without the left account navigation.

I supossed is something in wishlist layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this happens because of the the layout handle `wishlist_index_index`.

In this handle the first thing that happens is a call to `<update handle="customer_account" />` what this means is that the layout handle `customer_account` will also be applied to this page. This handle is the part that includes the left column.

If you simply do not want the left column at all you could add a local.xml file with the layout.

```
<wishlist_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>left</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</wishlist_index_index>
```

This should remove the left column from the main wishlist page.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you just need to edit your wishlist XML layout:

Open `app/design/frontend/[PACKAGE]/[THEME]/layout/wishlist.xml` and inside the `<wishlist_index_index>` handler, add the folowing lines:

```
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

- `[PACKAGE]` and `[THEME]` reflect your active frontend package and theme.